# How to show Progress Dialog in listview

Tags: android, listview, progressdialog

I have a ListView and in the fill method I want that when I click on each items Progress Dialog showing (for loading)

here is my fill method

```
public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<RssParser.Item> adapter, final RssParser.Item item, final int position)
{  
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                ActivityStartup.handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ActivityStartup.dismissLoadingDialog();
                        txtTitle.setText(item.title);
                        txtDate.setText(item.pubDate);
                        txt_time.setText(item.time);
                        txtDescription.setText(item.description);
                        layoutRoot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                 **//\\  here I want to display Progress Dialog //\\**

                                Intent intent = new Intent(G.context, Adapter_Description.class)
                                        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.putExtra("INPUT", item.link + "");
                                intent.putExtra("INPUT_DESC", item.description + "");
                                G.context.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

            }
        });
        thread.start();
```

I write this but it has error on **"new ProgressDialog(this);"**
and the error said:
 The constructor ProgressDialog(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined

```
if (progress == null) {
progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setTitle("title");
progress.setMessage("loading");
}
progress.show();
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Have you tried it yet? Also, why do you want to show one *just before* going to another activity?

Comment: I want to use it as a loading

Comment: If you are loading data in the next activity then that's where the progress dialog should be.

Comment: pass yourActivityName.this instead this in ProgressDialog constructor.

Comment: I want that when I clicked on the item ProgressDialog opens and showing the loading while app fetch all the data from the network.

Comment: Naveed Ali: I dont think so Because my fill method is like this:   public void fill(final ArrayAdapter<RssParser.Item> adapter, final RssParser.Item item, final int position)

Comment: Which Activity is getting the network data? If it's the next one then the dialog should go there. Anyway, yes you need `ActivityName.this` or `v.getContext()` or some other valid `Context`

Comment: when I use v.getContext() I got Null pointer Exeption